# Как вывести тип значения (минимальное, максимальное, среднее) и величину значения в 2 колонки

Tags: sql

Как в 2 колонки (тип зарплаты и величина зарплаты) вывести максимальное значение зарплаты, минимальное и среднее из таблички, в которой в одной из колонок есть значение зарплаты сотрудников.

Comment: структуру таблицы и пару строк приведите

Comment: Думаю вам нужны функции агрегирования - min max и avg.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'MIN' as  type, MIN(salary) AS salary FROM table
union all
SELECT 'MAX' as  type, MAX(salary) AS salary FROM table
union all
SELECT 'AVG' as  type, AVG(salary) AS salary FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Для MySQL в 4 столбца

```
SELECT MIN(salary), MAX(salary), AVG(salary), type 
FROM table
GROUP BY TYPE
```

В 2 столбца

```
SELECT salary, type FROM (
    SELECT MIN(salary) AS salary, type 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY TYPE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(salary) AS salary, type 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY TYPE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT AVG(salary) AS salary, type 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY TYPE
) AS t1 ORDER BY type, salary
```